# How to export the report that created using Telerik Reporting (.trdx) to pdf?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, pdf, export, telerik-reporting

I use Telerik Report Designer (Standalone) to design a report (.trdx), how do I export it to pdf file programmatically in C# code?

Answer (score 1):

I used below code snippet. It deserializes the .trdx file and then it creates a Report (Telerik.Reporting.Report) instance out of it. This report instance can then be converted to a pdf.

```
       System.Xml.XmlReaderSettings settings = new System.Xml.XmlReaderSettings();
       settings.IgnoreWhitespace = true;

            //read the .trdx file contents
            using (System.Xml.XmlReader xmlReader = System.Xml.XmlReader.Create(path_to your_trdx_file, settings))
            {
                Telerik.Reporting.XmlSerialization.ReportXmlSerializer xmlSerializer =
                    new Telerik.Reporting.XmlSerialization.ReportXmlSerializer();

                //deserialize the .trdx report XML contents
                Telerik.Reporting.Report report = (Telerik.Reporting.Report)
                    xmlSerializer.Deserialize(xmlReader);

                string mimType = string.Empty;
                string extension = string.Empty;
                Encoding encoding = null;

                // call Render() and retrieve raw array of bytes
                // write the pdf file
                byte[] buffer = Telerik.Reporting.Processing.ReportProcessor.Render(
                "PDF", report, null, out mimType, out extension, out encoding);
                // create a new file on disk and write the byte array to the file
                FileStream fs = new FileStream(Path_you_need_to_save_the_pdf_file, FileMode.Create);
                fs.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
                fs.Flush();
                fs.Close();
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you user Telerik reporting 2012 or newer the above code needs to be changed to this

```
enter code here
```

XmlReaderSettings settings = new XmlReaderSettings();
settings.IgnoreWhitespace = true;

```
        //read the .trdx file contents
        using (
            XmlReader xmlReader =
                XmlReader.Create(you trdx file path,
                    settings))
        {
            ReportXmlSerializer xmlSerializer =
                new ReportXmlSerializer();

            //deserialize the .trdx report XML contents
            Report report = (Report)xmlSerializer.Deserialize(xmlReader);

            Telerik.Reporting.InstanceReportSource instanceReportSource = new Telerik.Reporting.InstanceReportSource
            {
                ReportDocument = report
            };
            string mimType = string.Empty;
            string extension = string.Empty;
            //Encoding encoding = null;

            // call Render() and retrieve raw array of bytes
            // write the pdf file
            ReportProcessor reportProcessor = new ReportProcessor();

            RenderingResult renderingResult = reportProcessor.RenderReport("DOCX", instanceReportSource, null);
            // create a new file on disk and write the byte array to the file
            FileStream fs = new FileStream(@"D:\test\Dashboard.DOCX", FileMode.Create);
            fs.Write(renderingResult.DocumentBytes, 0, renderingResult.DocumentBytes.Length);
            fs.Flush();
            fs.Close();
        }
```